# Java Graph Visualisation Library: Nodes with multiple connect points

Tags: java, graph, jung

Can anyone recommend a Java Graph Visualisation library in which graph nodes can be rendered with multiple connect points?

For example, supposing a graph node represents a processor that takes input from two sources and produces output.  This would be visualised as 3 vertices.  However, clearly each vertex has a defined role in the workflow and therefore ideally my node would appear with 3 distinct connection points that the user could attach vertices to.

I've taken a look at JUNG but I don't think it will suit my needs.

Any recommendations welcome; either on specific libraries or alternative approaches I can take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try JGraph's java library

[JGRAPH](http://www.jgraph.com/)

It has a good amount of functionality and I have used it with success before. The only thing is that the documentation is a bit lacking, but if you read through some examples and code its pretty good when you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) (http://www.jgraph.com/). I used [jgraph-5.14.0.0](https://github.com/eamocanu/spellcheck.graph/tree/master/external%20API) for a similar project before. Here are the graphs that I made for another project: https://github.com/eamocanu/spellcheck.graph/tree/master/graph%20photos